# How to download text from web in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to show text from txt file from server in label. For example I have `http://www.example.com/test.txt` file on server and here is some text and I want to show this downloaded text as label in my app. I tried

```
- (IBAction)getText:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://http://mrrandom.cba.pl/test.txt"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
    _label.text = content; 
}
```

but it didn't work for me. Do you have any ideas? Thanks for help!

Comment: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mrrandom.cba.pl/test.txt"]; `

Comment: My god I'm blind...Thank you very much! ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your url.

Instead of writing

`http://http://mrrandom.cba.pl/test.txt`

You should write

`http://mrrandom.cba.pl/test.txt`

Also, you should consider doing "downloads" on a background thread using [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/).

For more info about performing download on iOS, please refer to the documentation about [the URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i).

Comment: Yes ,I know, it works now :) Thank you!